# Add link to the suggested edit in review beta

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

In review beta, when showing a suggested edit, a link to the page for that suggested edit (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/325184) is not shown. I think this link can be useful in some circumstances, can it be added?

For example, when I notice that someone else already rejected the edit with a custom message and I want to look at that message. Or if I refresh the page and it says that this edit was already dealt with and I want to see whether it was accepted or rejected.

Answer (score 2):

In the page Review history you can already find all the links to the suggested edits you acted on; I guess https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history is enough.

You're right: When you review a suggested edit with the new tool, you have only the *Rendered output diffs* and *Markdown diffs* options; there isn't the permalink anymore.

Using the URL of the current reviewed suggested edit in the browser URL bar without review/ also doesn't work. It's a bit misleading; we can suppose the IDs are the same, but it's not the case.

Definitively, a permalink to the approved/rejected edit (with the correct ID) should be added when *This item is no longer reviewable.* is displayed.

Comment: I don't mean just edits I already acted on. I guess in both cases I mentioned, the edit would show there, but I would have to look for it (and it may not be on the first page anymore).

Comment: @svick Ok, I understand better what you want. You're right when you review a suggested edit with the new tool you have only the option `rendered output diffs`, `markdown diffs` and no more permalink option. I guess it's not so usefull because you get the url of the current suggested edit in your browser URL bar.

Comment: Good UI shouldn't require me to fiddle with the URL. And I'm capable of doing that, but what about people from english.SE? Also, it doesn't even work: the ID in review beta seems to be different from the edit ID. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/162830 is an edit to the darwin tag wiki, but http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/162830 is edit to some question about paypal.

Comment: @svick You're right,I've edited the answer.